How to use NFS mounted files for IGV JS component?
I have a web application which implements IGV JS component. For displaying IGV view, I need to pass a BAM file URL and a BAI file URL. Previously, my BAM and BAI files were stored in AWS S3 bucket - so I was using the AWS S3 Java SDK to generate presigned URLs for the files and send them from the backend - using these presigned URLs - IGV JS was showing the data/view.
Now, I am moving from AWS S3 to NAS (Network Attached Storage) - so I have used a NFS mount in my server (I was using goofys earlier to mount my S3 bucket to my server system). So, I want to pass these files as URLs into IGV component.
One approach is to generate a file token and then pass the URL along with the token - however, this process is extremely slow for me as my BAM files are around 4GB in size. Is there any alternative path I can take?

Is there a way for IGV JS to read the mounted files directly?
Is there a faster way to generate URLs for NAS files like AWS S3?

